# Can I use a T1 business router as regular home network router?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

I am trying to setup a home network with my existing cable modem. I am buying used router for this purpose. There is a SIEMENS se5940 T1 Business Gateway/router on sale on the local craigslist. I am wondering if it can be used as the home network router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T-carrier lines consists of multiple pairs of wires. It likely does not have a coax port for cable, and it probably doesn't have a ethernet jack for the modem.

Technically, you could reconfigure one of the internal ports into a WAN port. Being a business router, I would think it contains an internal configurable switch, but it's possible that it doesn't. Might be able to manage with VLANS, and it also depends if its DHCP client is configurable. You should also be aware that business routers are typically far more complicated than consumer routers; you may not even get a web interface to configure it with, and may require a terminal, virtual or otherwise.

EDIT: Found a datasheet for the router. Looks like it's a small business one, so on the bright side, it has a web-interface. On the other hand, it probably also means that it lacks the advanced capabilities to reassign ports (not completely sure about that; would need to see a manual to know). Also looks like it uses the RJ48C standard. While it *appears* to look like ethernet, it isn't pin compatible; different connector (RJ45 on your cable modem)

Comment: that means it is used without cable modem. It should be used where the T1 line is available. I have a cable modem to convert the cable to cat5 cable. So I should look for a home network router with a cat5 cable inlet. am I right?

Comment: Any consumer router should support your cable modem. Most unspecified business routers will be fine, too, if you feel the need for its advanced network utilities. You shouldn't have to specifically look for something to support your home network, because the cable modem already handles the most complicated part of basic internet (for a home network, anyway). If you have more needs in firewall, VPN, VLANs or routing/switching, then you should already know what you need.